# Refreshing the Action Bar in Android 3.0

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement an action bar within an activity.
Is it possible to "refresh" or re-inflate the action bar with a new menu(without restarting the activity)
The only way I have found so far is to leave the action bar empty and assign it a new customView every time I want it changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on your activity. Quoting [the documentation](http://goo.gl/PAePL):

> Declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. The onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) method will be called the next time it needs to be displayed.