# Android ActionBar Recreate Options Menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, options-menu

When using the ActionBar in Android, how do you refresh the options menu?  I have tried hiding and showing the bar, along with getting a new instance of it with "getSupportActionBar()"

I am trying to implement a Login/Logout button that will change dynamically based on the state of the user.

Here is my onCreateOptionsMenu method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (loggedIn)
        menu.add(0, MENU2, 0, "Logout").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    else
        menu.add(0, MENU2, 0, "Login").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    menu.add(0, MENU1, 0, "Home").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refreshing the Action Bar in Android 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602534/refreshing-the-action-bar-in-android-3-0)

Comment: General Question - What is Stackoverflow etiquette for choosing a best answer when two answers are the same and answered within about the same time of each other as well?

Comment: Better answers (more detail, code samples, links, etc.) trump faster answers. For answers of equivalent merit in both areas... flip a coin?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Invalidate the menu with [invalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) and then put your code in the [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) area.

Answer (score 12):

In your FragmentActivity call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`

This is also a public method, so if you want to refresh it from a fragment call `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()`

BTW, if you're using SherlockActionBar you'll need to call `getSherlockActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()`
from the fragment, or you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 10):

```
invalidateOptionsMenu()
```

requires API level 11...

for lower API use:

```
supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()
```