# Trying to hide the menu item when there are no views

Tags: java, android, xml, menuitem

I'm trying to build an app that generates buttons dynamically per floatActionButton click.  This aspect works fine.  But if there are no views, there shouldn't be a delete menu item on the action bar.  At the start of the app, since there are no items, there is no menu item but I need the menu item to show up once I start adding views.  I tried to work it with if statements but it still did not work.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int counter = 0;

    FloatingActionButton addingSemester;
    Button semesterButton;
    LinearLayout semesterLayout;
    GridLayout semesterGridLayout;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams portraitLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addingSemester = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addActionButton);
        semesterLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

        semesterGridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.semester_grid_layout);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();

        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("counter");

            for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                addSemesterButton(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addSemesterButton(int id) {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        double width = (size.x)/3;

        semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
        semesterButton.setId(id + 1);
        semesterButton.setText("Semester " + (id + 1));
        semesterButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        semesterButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        portraitLayoutParams.setMargins(24, 24, 24, 24);

        if (MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
            GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(24, 24, 24, 24);
            params.width = (int) width;
            params.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            semesterButton.setLayoutParams(params);
            semesterGridLayout.addView(semesterButton);
        } else if (!MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
            semesterLayout.addView(semesterButton);
            semesterButton.setLayoutParams(portraitLayoutParams);
        }

        setOnLongClickListenerForSemesterButton();
    }

    public void addTextView(int id){
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        double width = (size.x);

        TextView instructionsPromptTextView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        instructionsPromptTextView.setId(id);
        instructionsPromptTextView.setText(R.string.click_the_button_to_add_semesters);
        instructionsPromptTextView.setTextSize((float)width);
        instructionsPromptTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        instructionsPromptTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        relativeLayout.addView(instructionsPromptTextView);


        if(id == 0){
            instructionsPromptTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }

    public void onFloatActionButtonClick(View view) {
        if (counter < 8) {
            addSemesterButton(counter);

            counter++;
            setOnLongClickListenerForSemesterButton();

        } else if (counter == 8) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You cannot add more than 8 semesters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (counter == 0){
            addTextView(counter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.delete);
        if(counter == 0){
            item.setVisible(false);
        }

        if(counter > 0){
            MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            item.setVisible(true);
        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.delete) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Delete entry")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete everything?")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterGridLayout.removeAllViews();
                                } else if (!MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterLayout.removeAllViews();
                                }
                                counter = 0;
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
                return true;
            }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putInt("counter", counter);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void setOnLongClickListenerForSemesterButton() {
        semesterButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                final Button b = (Button) v;
                b.setTag(b.getText().toString());
                b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                b.setText("Delete");

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Delete entry");
                        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterGridLayout.removeView(b);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < semesterGridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                        ((Button) semesterGridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setText("Semester " + (i + 1));
                                    }
                                } else if (!MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterLayout.removeView(b);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < semesterLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                        ((Button) semesterLayout.getChildAt(i)).setText("Semester " + (i + 1));
                                    }
                                }
                                counter--;
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                b.cancelLongPress();
                                b.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
                                b.setText(b.getTag().toString());
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is the stacktrace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: myapp.onur.journeygpacalculator, PID: 22605
                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4711)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5623)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4706)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5623) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.add(int, int, int, java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:493)
                                                                                     at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:190)
                                                                                     at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:111)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:113)
                                                                                     at myapp.onur.journeygpacalculator.MainActivity.inflateMenu(MainActivity.java:182)
                                                                                     at myapp.onur.journeygpacalculator.MainActivity.onFloatActionButtonClick(MainActivity.java:168)
```

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100641/android-actionbar-recreate-options-menu can help

Comment: It recommends `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method but that doesn't do anything.  I just implemented it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting it invisible only in `onCreateOptionsMenu` set it in your action button click too like below

```
    MenuItem item;

    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            item = menu.findItem(R.id.delete);
            item.setVisible(false);

            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }


        public void onFloatActionButtonClick(View view) {
            if (counter < 8) {
                addSemesterButton(counter);

                counter++;
                setOnLongClickListenerForSemesterButton();
                item.setVisible(true);

            } else if (counter == 8) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You cannot add more than 8 semesters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                item.setVisible(true);
            } else if (counter == 0){
                addTextView(counter);
                item.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure about your referencing?  How did you reference item and inflateMenu?  If I copy/paste your code, I know I'll get errors.

Comment: Try it and let me know I have edit some of the code.

Comment: The app crashed.  The inflateMenu method doesn't work.

Comment: what your logcat says, are you sure you added the above code properly ?

Comment: It works fine but the only problem is that the menu item remains after I delete everything.  There should be no menuItem in the actionBar if the views have no children.  So each time I click the delete button, the button should be invisible after everything is deleted.

Comment: And become visible when I add views.

Comment: ok after both these lines `semesterLayout.removeAllViews();` , `semesterGridLayout.removeView(b);` add `item.setVisible(false);`

Comment: That's literally what I did and it still remains.

Comment: and invalidatet the Options Menu? `invalidateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: Edit your question and post the menu.xml file

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Update `onCreateOptionsMenu()` as below, to hide `delete` option when app starts first:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    itemDelete = menu.findItem(R.id.delete);

    // Required to hide delete option when app starts first
    itemDelete.setVisible(false); 

    return true;
}
```

**2.** Add below method to `update` the state of `delete` option.

```
    public void updateOptionMenu() {
        if (counter > 0) 
            item.setVisible(true);
        else
            item.setVisible(false);    
    }
```

**3.** Call updateOptionMenu()  method from all places where the `counter` value changes like: `onFloatActionButtonClick()` and `AlertDialog's onClick()` methods.

**Here is the full code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    MenuItem itemDelete;
    int counter = 0;

    FloatingActionButton addingSemester;
    Button semesterButton;
    LinearLayout semesterLayout;
    GridLayout semesterGridLayout;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams portraitLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addingSemester = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addActionButton);
        semesterLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

        semesterGridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.semester_grid_layout);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();

        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            counter = savedInstanceState.getInt("counter");

            for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                addSemesterButton(i);
            }
        }

        addTextView(counter);
    }

    public void addSemesterButton(int id) {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        double width = (size.x)/3;

        semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
        semesterButton.setId(id + 1);
        semesterButton.setText("Semester " + (id + 1));
        semesterButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        semesterButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        portraitLayoutParams.setMargins(24, 24, 24, 24);

        if (MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
            GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(24, 24, 24, 24);
            params.width = (int) width;
            params.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            semesterButton.setLayoutParams(params);
            semesterGridLayout.addView(semesterButton);
        } else if (!MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
            semesterLayout.addView(semesterButton);
            semesterButton.setLayoutParams(portraitLayoutParams);
        }

        setOnLongClickListenerForSemesterButton();
    }

    public void addTextView(int id){
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        double width = (size.x);

        TextView instructionsPromptTextView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        instructionsPromptTextView.setId(id);
        instructionsPromptTextView.setText(R.string.click_the_button_to_add_semesters);
        instructionsPromptTextView.setTextSize((float)width);
        instructionsPromptTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        instructionsPromptTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        relativeLayout.addView(instructionsPromptTextView);

        /*
        if(id == 0){
            instructionsPromptTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }*/

    }

    public void onFloatActionButtonClick(View view) {
        if (counter < 8) {
            addSemesterButton(counter);

            counter++;
            setOnLongClickListenerForSemesterButton();

            // Required to show delete option
            updateOptionMenu(); 

        } else if (counter == 8) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You cannot add more than 8 semesters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 

        // Will never be called because counter == 0 will be consumed by first if condition 
        /*
        else if (counter == 0){
            addTextView(counter); // Move it to onCreate()
        }*/
    }

    public void updateOptionMenu() {
        if (counter > 0) 
            item.setVisible(true);
        else
            item.setVisible(false);    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        itemDelete = menu.findItem(R.id.delete);

        // Required to hide delete option when app starts first
        itemDelete.setVisible(false); 

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.delete) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Delete entry")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete everything?")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterGridLayout.removeAllViews();
                                } else if (!MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterLayout.removeAllViews();
                                }

                                counter = 0;
                                updateOptionMenu(); // Required to hide option item when all views are removed
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
                return true;
            }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putInt("counter", counter);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void setOnLongClickListenerForSemesterButton() {
        semesterButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                final Button b = (Button) v;
                b.setTag(b.getText().toString());
                b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                b.setText("Delete");

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Delete entry");
                        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterGridLayout.removeView(b);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < semesterGridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                        ((Button) semesterGridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setText("Semester " + (i + 1));
                                    }
                                } else if (!MainActivity.this.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape)) {
                                    semesterLayout.removeView(b);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < semesterLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                        ((Button) semesterLayout.getChildAt(i)).setText("Semester " + (i + 1));
                                    }
                                }
                                counter--;
                                updateOptionMenu(); // Required to hide delete item if this button is last button to be removed
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                b.cancelLongPress();
                                b.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
                                b.setText(b.getTag().toString());
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        });
                        builder.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this will help~